# Canadian Visa Biometrics - do calluses affect fingerprints being taken?

Tags: visas, canada

I am a guitar player and I have calluses on my fingertips. Canadian visa applications require biometrics to be submitted. Would it impact my application?

IRCC suggests (on the website) that we should wait for the fingers to heal before giving the biometrics. I have already waited for 10 days and I can't afford to wait anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Among a bunch of rock climbing friends and a network of plenty more on forums/social media, I'd like to think I would have heard about this if it was an issue.

Only problems I and others seem to notice are consumer grade fingerprint scanners not recognising your fingerprint

I'd say you can stop waiting!